# Check if twitterbot/facebookbot is scraping your site in Express

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, twitter

Within my route I want to render a page if twitter or facebook scrape it but redirect if a user navigates to it from those links on social. However, i'm always getting redirected as the bots are scraping my home page.

Does anyone know where to find the bot names Twitter and Facebook use?

This is what i've got so far :

```
  if (userAgent.startsWith('facebookexternalhit/1.1') || userAgent === 'Facebot' || userAgent.startsWith('Twitterbot')) {
    res.render('share', {
      title: 'Express',
      meta_image: image_data[2],
      layout: false,
      site_name: image_data[3],
      social_button_group: social_button_group,
      possible_remaining: possible_remaining
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
```

Comment: For facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

Comment: @HirenS. cheers man :) Still struggling to find the Twitter bot I thought it would be on their docs but can't find ti

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#crawling